# Using indexes or triggers to ensure uniqueness

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 3 primary keys (let's call them FirstName, SecondName, VersionID) and one data column (EmailAddress).

I want to ensure that when when data is inserted, the data column is unique for any of the first 2 columns.

Ie, any EmailAddress is unique for any combination of FirstName, SecondName. There can however be multiple values of that same EmailAddress with the same FirstName and SecondName but different versionID.

My initial thoughts were to create a index on these columns to ensure uniqueness, but I can't quite work out how to do so.... Then I've considered triggers but I'm not sure how to construct them.

What is the most efficient way, and how would I proceed?

Comment: what you're looking for is a multiple column unique constraint.

Comment: yes I thought that might be it, but how do I structure it? If I create an index on FirstName, SecondName, EmailAddress then JohnSmith and JakeSmith could have the same EmailAddress

Answer (score 0):

```
# firstname, secondname & emailaddress together must be unique
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT ux_email_firstname_secondname_versionid
UNIQUE (firstname, secondname, emailaddress);

# emailaddress and versionid together must be unique
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD CONTRAINT ex_emailaddress_versionid
UNIQUE (emailaddress, versionid);
```

Something like that which makes the combination of the three colummns unique, but if one varies it's no longer a like match.

Comment: If I create an index on FirstName, SecondName, EmailAddress then can't JohnSmith and JakeSmith could have the same EmailAddress? This isn't what I'm after

Comment: @mcmillab: they could, but you say there could be multiple emails in the database, as long as their versionid was varies. You can add another constraint for `(EmailAddress, versionID)`...

Comment: but then JohnSmith version1 and JakeSmith version2 could have the same email address

Comment: @mcmillab: Then I'm not sure I understand what you're after. i can only base my solution off your original parameters which were that the name and email be unique, but that the email could exist multiple times as long as the version varied. The solution (to whichever extent) is to create a unique constraint, but it's going to be up to you and your needs to implement it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
  ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name_name UNIQUE (FirstName, SecondName, versionID , EmailAddress)
```

Comment: If I create an index on FirstName, SecondName, EmailAddress then can't JohnSmith and JakeSmith could have the same EmailAddress? This isn't what I'm after

Comment: @mcmillab with the 4 columns defined as a multiple unique index it should be ok.

Comment: then JohnSmith version1 and JohnSmith version2 can't have the same email address

Comment: If the version_id is different for each of them, yes they can have the same email address.

Answer (score 0):

I'd throw out any ideas about triggers for what you're talking about.  And based on your comments above, you just need a unique constraint on Email Address.

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name
  ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (EmailAddress)
```

I would advise against this, as a user could enter a wrong email address that would block another user from entering their email address correctly.

Your best bet is to use the query written by @TheEwook:

> Multiple unique constraint:
>
> ALTER TABLE your_table   ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name_name UNIQUE
>   (FirstName, SecondName, versionID , EmailAddress) share|edit

If you're concerned about having 2 users trying to use the same email address, then you would want to handle that when doing the insert by checking to see what the max version for each user is, and compare that email to the one being inserted.